# Export gridview in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two gridviews on a page. When I click on Button3 it exports gridview data to excel perfectly.

but when I click on Button5 it exports data of gridview to excel and in excel file contains only:

```
<style> .textmode { } </style><div>
```

here is my c# code:

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportFile.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            //GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
            this.GridView1.DataBind();

            GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }

            GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
    protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportFile.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            GridView2.AllowPaging = false;
            GridView2.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            GridView2.Columns[1].Visible = false;
            //GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "#FFFFFF");
            this.GridView2.DataBind();

            GridView2.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in GridView2.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                cell.BackColor = GridView2.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
            {
                row.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView2.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.BackColor = GridView2.RowStyle.BackColor;
                    }
                    cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                }
            }

            GridView2.RenderControl(hw);

            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any data other than style in your `sw` for button 5?

Comment: May be check the html part of the code for gridview2, is there html error or missing close tags?

Comment: @KiranHegde in my GridView2 there is no error

Comment: @SidM no i am not getting any data

Comment: are there any rows in your `GridView2`?

Comment: Can you paste your HTML code ?